# Pig Latin: Filter number <5 and >= 5 in chararray (text and numbers)

Tags: apache-pig

How can I filter or group those with less than 5 years and those with more than 5 years. I am very new to Pig Latin. The ID, e.g. BUS2003 should be left as is.

Input Data

```
ID,Experience
BUS2003,More than 17 years teaching experience
BUS1303,2 years teaching experience
BUS4543,13 plus years of teaching experience; 4 plus years of corporate experience
BUS2103,4 year + 6 years in business
BUS2913,8 yrs teaching experience
```

I know how to load the data in to PigStorage or CSVloader, however, I am having a hard time solving the Experience due to words and numbers being together.

Desired result:

```
**Less than five years**
BUS1303,2 years teaching experience
BUS2103,4 year + 6 years in business

**Equal or greater than five years**
BUS2003,More than 17 years teaching experience
BUS4543,13 plus years of teaching experience; 4 plus years of corporate experience
BUS2913,8 yrs teaching experience
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extract the number and then split.This should get you what you are looking for

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (a1:chararray,a2:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE a1,a2,REGEX_EXTRACT(a2,'(\\d*)',1) as exp:int;
C = SPLIT B INTO C1 IF B.exp < 5, C2 IF B.exp >= 5;
DUMP C1;
DUMP C2;
```